# PInvoke addressing

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a method in C++ with two arguments: byte and ushort, that returns pointer to very difficult structure (it's a union amoung nearly all structures presented in the C++ project).

When I call this method using DllImport in C#, for example passing it 1 and 2, it invokes with some random byte number and 1 (so the first argument is passed as the second, and the real first is taken from some different address of the memory).

The only one explanation I can think of that return structure isn't mapped correctly, and because of that all parameters have offset. But I don't know how to check it. Is there any tools that can show me addresses and sizes of the marshalled data, generated by the C#, so I can check them with the address I receive in the C++? Or any other solution you can suggest.

**--- Update ---**

After commenting code structures for C++ and C# I reduced testing code to this:
C++:

```
enum PrimitiveType: unsigned short
enum ErrorType : unsigned char 

typedef struct
{
  PrimitiveType Primitive;
  unsigned char InstNo;       /* The instance number. */
  ErrorType ErrorCode;         /* ERR_NO_ERROR */
  unsigned char Active;                      /* True = relay active */
 } GetRelayCfmType;
```

sizeof(GetRelayCfmType) = 5

C#:

```
enum PrimitiveType : ushort
enum ErrorType : byte

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GetRelayCfmType
    {
        public PrimitiveType Primitive;
        public byte InstNo;                         /* The instance number. */
        public ErrorType ErrorCode;          /* RTX2300_ERR_NO_ERROR */
        public byte Active;                      /* True = relay active */
    };
```

Marshal.Sizeof(new GetRelayCfmType()) == 6.

Why sizes differ in one byte?
**Upd.**

Now my function is (C++) :

```
__declspec(dllexport) GetRelayCfmType __stdcall GetRelay_Blocking(unsigned char InstNo, RelayNoType No)

 enum RelayNoType : unsigned char
```

so in C# I have:

```
[DllImport(DLL_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
    public static extern GetRelayCfmType GetRelay_Blocking(byte InstNo, RelayNoType No);

enum RelayNoType : byte
```

Now the picture is full.

Comment: Step 1: show enough code for us to help.

Comment: Have you used http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120 to check the DLLimport code is correct?

Comment: That's like 100+ structures. As I said the function is very simple - it accepts byte and ushort, return value is the bastard. It is union made from those 100+ structures. Also I cannot upload it because of NDA, and cannot trancate it because of I don't know where the problem is. That's why I'm asking you not to point me where the problem is, but instead help me with some examples how such problems are debugged.

Comment: Mike, yes. The whole structures and dllimports were generated by this tool.

Comment: Are you sure you've imported the right method? In a dll I was working with recently there were 2 versions of a method declared in the header file that I was working from, one for Mac and one for Windows with subtly different signatures.
I'd imported the wrong one and it was behaving incorrectly as a result of the parameters not being in the order the dll was expecting.

Comment: You'll need to find help from other people that signed that NDA.  Start with the owner of the code.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention.aspx)?

Comment: Hans, I don't think that's possible. The owner of the code is very very busy man, it took me two days to get sources from him.

Comment: @svick - The calling convention doesn't seem like it would effect the size of the structure.

Comment: Svick, yep. I'm using stdcall. I have like 200+ functions mapped and only some of them aren't working

Comment: @Ramhound, will you show me what I've done wrong?

Comment: @Ramhound, you're right, the calling convention wouldn't affect that, but I think that's not the problem. The size of the struct that's returned should have no effect on parameters that Are passed in. Archeg, can you post the method signature? Ideally both in C++ and C#.

Comment: @Archeg - If I were to hazard a guess its because you don't indicate the Pack value.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what the Pack means, but I tried values 0,1,2,4,8,16 - nothing changes

Comment: @Archeg - Do research on the Name Parameters argument for **StructLayoutAttribute** This against my better judgement because you have not done your research and are using automatic tools for you.  Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx

Comment: I gurantee if you use the Explicit layout and indicate the Pack value is 1 it will solve the problem.  Might not solve any other problem, but will solve the problem your asking about.

Comment: Tried. Maybe I'm wrong in something: I set Expicit, Pack = 1, Size = 5. Fields offsets: 0, 2, 3, 4 (first one is ushort - two bytes). The behaivious hasn't changed at all. (I checked - my C++ has #pragma pack(push, 1) so the pack should be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly need more information before you request our help. Take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf(v=vs.100).aspx take notice of the statement that is made.

> Although you can use the Marshal.SizeOf method, the value returned by
>   this method is not always the same as the value returned by sizeof.
>   Marshal.SizeOf returns the size after the type has been marshaled,
>   whereas sizeof returns the size as it has been allocated by the common
>   language runtime, including any padding.

I suspect its because of the padding within the structure.  You have allowed .NET to Sequential layout the structure.  This of course allows it to guess at certain things.  I would use the **Explicit** set the **Pack** value and perhaps even **Size** value.